# Call html() function on $.tmpl function's return object

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/M4PnqMnbnZtNbVFcNobn?p=preview).

I am trying to get the html content out of a jquery template and its data. Is n't the return type of `tmpl` a jquery wrapped object?

This code,

```
$.each($('#movieTemplate').tmpl(movies), function(idx,elt){
  tmplContent = tmplContent + elt.html()
  });
```

throws error as

```
elt.html is not a function
```

Note: I can make it work with an alternate way as shown in plunker

But i am trying to figure out the object type of $.tmpl's return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.createElement` to create an html container and instead of concatenating the html as string, append the html

```
var movies = [
    { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
    { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
    { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
]

var tmplContent = $("<div />").append($.tmpl('  <li>    <b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})  </li>', movies)).html()
$('#results-0').html(tmplContent)

var tmplContent = document.createElement('div');
$.each($('#movieTemplate').tmpl(movies), function(idx,elt){
    tmplContent.appendChild(elt);
    //tmplContent = tmplContent + elt.toString()
});

$('#results-1').html(tmplContent)
```

Or if you still want to use it as string, you can do it this way

```
$.each($('#movieTemplate').tmpl(movies), function(idx,elt){
    tmplContent = tmplContent + $(elt).prop('outerHTML');
});
```